# difference between onsizechanged and surfacechanged?

Tags: android

what is difference between `onsizechanged()` and `surfacechanged()` methods ??

`onsizechanged()` is called when the size of view has changed  while `surfacechanged()` is  called when surface is changed ...  so both methods will be called simultaneously when a change in size happens ??

how this actually occurs  and **when to use these two**...

Also can u provide some **links of the tutorial on view framework** for better understanding other than Android developers ???

Comment: This is a totally legitimate Q. The main Q is "what is difference between onsizechanged() and surfacechanged() methods ?? ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all the two methods are completely different, even though they get called together in the case of surfaceview.

- [onSizeChanged](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/view/View.java#View.onSizeChanged%28int,int,int,int%29) is a callback method for View objects in general.

> This is called immediately after any structural changes (format or size) have been made to the surface. You should at this point update the imagery in the surface. This method is always called at least once, after surfaceCreated(android.view.SurfaceHolder).

- [onSurfaceChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html) is a callback method for a surfaceholder interface. which many View objects implement (GLSurfaceView, SurfaceView).

> This is called during layout when the size of this view has changed. If you were just added to the view hierarchy, you're called with the old values of 0.

Now **technically** both would be called at the same time. but `onSurfaceChanged` will be called alone if you change the [PixelFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html) of your surface object.